# include openssl library in INET framework of OMNeT++

Tags: openssl, omnet++, inet

I want to integrate OpenSSL in the mgmt layer of ieee80211 in INET. When I try to follow the normal procedure, i.e., including the library path in the INET src folder using Makemake->link->openssl libraries, it creates problems as INET creates a shared library libINET.dll. Please help me as I want to integrate AES encryption on the mgmt layer of IEEE80211. It's really important for my work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you precise what problems creates INET? INET creates libINET.dll by default.

Comment: Hi Jerzy. The problem got solved. I have included the libraries and headers in the makefile of INET. It worked.

Comment: If you can describe the exact steps you needed as an answer to your own question (yes, that's possible and even encouraged here) , you can mark it as resolved in a few days time. That will help other people in the future with similar problems.

Comment: Ya sure, I will

Answer (score 1):

To integrate OpenSSL in the INET framework of omnet++, the steps are as follows:

1. Copy the folder OpenSSL in the inet/3rdparty folder of omnet++. I am assuming that you have OpenSSL installed on your system. If not, firstly please install it on the system, and then copy the folder. Please ensure that the name of the folder does not contain any spaces.
2. In the lib folder of OpenSSL, remove all the files except, 4785cca and libeay32.
3. In the Makefrag file placed at inet/src paste the following lines:
   `INCLUDE_PATH += -I../3rdparty/OpenSSL-Win64/include`
   `LIBS += -Wl,-rpath,$(abspath ../3rdparty/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/*.*)`
   `LIBS += -Wl,-rpath,$(abspath ../3rdparty/OpenSSL-Win64/libeay32.dll)`
   `LIBS += -Wl,-rpath,$(abspath ../3rdparty/OpenSSL-Win64/ssleay.dll)`
   `LIBS += -Wl,-rpath,$(abspath ../3rdparty/OpenSSL-Win64/libssl32.dll)`

where OpenSSL-Win64 is the name of the folder. Please change the name as per your folder name.
4. Compile the inet folder from omnet++ IDE and it should work.
Note: I am using Windows 10 and OpenSSL 1.0 version.